# Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\rho}}{[x^{\rho} + \cos(\pi \rho)]^2 + \sin^2(\pi \rho)}\,\text{d}x$ by Residue Theorem

Tags: definite-integrals, residue-calculus

For $0 < \rho < 1$,  evaluate using Residue Theorem the following integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\rho}}{[x^{\rho} + \cos(\pi \rho)]^2 + \sin^2(\pi \rho)}\,\text{d}x. \qquad\qquad(**)$$
Procedures for the case when $\int_0^{\infty} P(x)/Q(x)\text{d}x$ and $\int_0^{\infty} x^{\alpha}/Q(x)\text{d}x$ where $P(x), Q(x)$ are polynomials such that $Q(x)\neq 0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$ are found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210418061631/http://faculty.up.edu/wootton/Complex/Chapter11.pdf). However, I can't find any procedures for the integral above.

**EDIT:**

I was originally studying the following integral known to have no closed form other than an infinite series (which I do not want) in the general case:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{\rho}}{\left[u^{\rho} + \cos (\pi\rho)\right]^2  + \sin^2(\pi\rho)}e^{-\lambda u}\text{d}u\qquad\qquad (--)$$

Thus, I shifted by attention instead toward some parts of its kernel which is the previous integral. As pointed out by @J.G., it might lead to some complication if I choose the form (**) wherein the numerator is $x^{\rho}$. So my question now boils down to what should be numerator of choice that can be rewritten out of (--) so that it is integrable to some closed (non-infinite series) form.

Comment: Hint: write the integrand as $\Re\frac{1}{x^\rho+e^{i\pi\rho}}$, substitute $y=x^\rho$, then use a keyhole contour, which appears unnamed in Sec. 3 of your link.

Comment: I'll get back to this and attempt using your approach.

Comment: Come to think of it, are you sure about that range for $\rho$? The large-$x$ asymptotic behaviour of the integrand is $x^{-\rho}$, which would just make the integral diverge.

Comment: Yeah, your right! I missed that. Let me edit it out first to the original context.

Comment: For your pre-edit problem I've just realized its integrand is a certain linear combination of the real and imaginary parts of $\frac{1}{x^\rho+e^{i\pi\rho}}$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: A possible approach for noninteger $\rho>1$ (continuity allows the evaluation to easily be deduced for integers once you have the result for nonintegers).

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$Simplify the integrand first: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\rho}{x^{2\rho}+2x^{\rho}\cos(\pi\rho)+1}\d x$$Then let's get rid of those powers, take $x\mapsto x^{1/\rho}$: $$\rho^{-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{1/\rho}}{x^2+2x\cos(\pi\rho)+1}\d x$$

And then this is suitable for branch-jumping with $x^{1/\rho}:=\exp(\rho^{-1}\log x)$ where $\log$ is induced from $0\le\arg<2\pi$, with the branch cut on $[0,\infty)$.

EDIT: you have now changed the problem, and my proposal is no longer suitable. Take $0<\rho<1$ and $\lambda>0$.

There is a standard factorisation of this, namely $x^{2\rho}+2x^{\rho}\cos(\pi\rho)+1=(x^{\rho}+e^{i\pi\rho})(x^{\rho}+e^{-i\pi\rho})$, so that the edited integrand is: $$\frac{1}{2i}\csc(\pi\rho)\cdot x^{\rho}e^{-\lambda x}\left(\frac{1}{x^{\rho}+e^{-i\pi\rho}}-\frac{1}{x^{\rho}+e^{i\pi\rho}}\right)$$So if: $$J:=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{\rho}}{x^{\rho}+e^{-i\pi\rho}}e^{-\lambda x}\d x$$Then your integral is: $$\frac{1}{2i}\csc(\pi\rho)(J-\overline{J})=\csc(\pi\rho)\cdot\Im(J)$$

It remains to calculate $J$. I am not sure about this. If you defined a logarithm with $0\le\arg<2\pi$ then this integral would equal: $$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{x^\rho}{x^{\rho}+1}e^{\lambda x}\d x=\lambda^{-1}-\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{e^{\lambda x}}{x^{\rho}+1}\d x$$
But I have my doubts that this last integral can be evaluated.